# How to set stage width and height to 100% React Konva

Tags: konvajs, react-konva

I want to set the width and height of my Stage to 100%. Kind of like this, so that it fills the parent div:

```
<Stage
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
></Stage>
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You have to set the `Konva.Stage` size with pixels value.

If you want to use `100%` values, you need to set such values to the parent `<div>` container of the stage with CSS. Then calculate the size of that `<div>` in pixels and use it for Stage.

Take a look into [Responsive Canvas Stage Demo](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Responsive_Canvas.html).

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#stage-parent');
stage.width(container.offsetWidth);
stage.height(container.offsetHeight);
```

Answer (score 8):

Since we cannot set the width and height of  to "100%", we have to instead find the width and height of its parent container in pixels and then set those values for the the  width and height

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"

import { Stage, Layer, Rect } from "react-konva"

export const View = () => {
  const divRef = useRef(null)
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  })

  // We cant set the h & w on Stage to 100% it only takes px values so we have to
  // find the parent container's w and h and then manually set those !
  useEffect(() => {
    if (divRef.current?.offsetHeight && divRef.current?.offsetWidth) {
      setDimensions({
        width: divRef.current.offsetWidth,
        height: divRef.current.offsetHeight
      })
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div ref={divRef}>
      <Stage width={dimensions.width} height={dimensions.height}>
        <Layer>
          <Rect fill="red" x={0} y={0} width={150} height={150}></Rect>
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    </div>
  )
}
```